# Is there a way to recursively filter by differences in date, but change which date I am referencing? [R]

Tags: r, data-cleaning, lubridate

```
df %>% 
  select(ID, Period, Date, Event) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, as.character) %>% 
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Period, Event) %>% 
  #filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Period, Event, Date) %>% 
  mutate(
     lead_1 = Date - lead(Date),
    lag_1 = Date - lag(Date)) %>%
  filter(is.na(lag_1) | lag_1 > 5)
```

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1177, 1177, 1177, 1177, 1177, 1177), Period = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Date = c("04/16/20", "04/17/20", "04/20/20", "04/20/20", "04/23/20", "04/25/20"), Event = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M")), row.names = c(NA, -6L),class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to filter events that are within a five day lag of the last event recording, but the reference for lag is to the previous row itself instead of the last row which should be kept

[image]

Here is an example of what the current output of the code is **Cur Output** and what it should be **Correct Output**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the lag time, I applied a rolling `cumsum` that gets reset to zero every time the threshold of > 5 days have passed since the last time the threshold was reached. I extended the data by three points to show better that it works. It uses a `for` loop and is not in pipes with `%>%` but I think it gives the desired output. The `df$out` column can then be filtered, and `df$cs` removed if not needed.

```
library(tidyverse)

ID <- c(1177, 1177, 1177, 1177, 1177,1177,1177, 1177)
Period <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Date <- c("04/16/2020", "04/17/2020", "04/20/2020", "04/20/2020", "04/23/2020","04/25/2020","04/27/2020","04/29/2020")
Event <- c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M")

df <- data.frame(ID,Period,Date,Event)

df %>% 
  select(ID, Period, Date, Event) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, as.character) %>% 
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Period, Event) %>% 
  #filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Period, Event, Date) %>% 
  mutate(
    lead_1 = Date - lead(Date),
    lag_1 = Date - lag(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(lag_1 = as.numeric(lag_1)) %>%
  mutate(cs = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(lag_1), 0, lag_1))) -> df

for(i in 1:length(df$lag_1)){
  remaining <- c((i+1):length(df$lag_1))
  if(df$cs[i] > 5){
    df$cs[i] <- 0
    if(i < length(df$lag_1)){
      df$cs[remaining] <- cumsum(ifelse(is.na(df$lag_1[remaining]), 0, df$lag_1[remaining]))
    }
  }
}

df$out <- as.numeric(df$cs==0)

> df

# # A tibble: 8 × 8
# # Groups:   ID, Period, Event [1]
#  ID    Period Date       Event lead_1  lag_1    cs   out
#  <chr> <chr>   <date>     <chr> <drtn>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1177  0      2020-04-16 M     -1 days    NA     0     1
# 2 1177  0      2020-04-17 M     -3 days     1     1     0
# 3 1177  0      2020-04-20 M      0 days     3     4     0
# 4 1177  0      2020-04-20 M     -3 days     0     4     0
# 5 1177  0      2020-04-23 M     -2 days     3     0     1
# 6 1177  0      2020-04-25 M     -2 days     2     2     0
# 7 1177  0      2020-04-27 M     -2 days     2     4     0
# 8 1177  0      2020-04-29 M     NA days     2     0     1
```